# Delete multiple users using IDs from all tables not specifying them using SQL Server Managment Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL and trying to learn, but I have one problem.

I'm looking at how to delete multiple users from all tables in the database.

I have tried this

```
exec UserDelete @CID = N'1',
                @UserID = '4' 
                @DeletedBy = N'System Administrator'
```

But this only deletes user with ID '4' from all the tables in `DB`. But how can I use this query if I want to delete multiple user, for example with `ID` 5,8,12...? When I add more than one `ID`, I get error.

Comment: If you must use this procedure, then put your IDs into a table, use a cursor to loop over those rows and execute this procedure for each ID in the cursor. Maybe ask the dba or the person that wrote this procedure for help.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you would normally delete rows using `delete`.  For instance:

```
delete from users
    where id in (5, 8, 12);
```

Someone has defined a stored procedure `UserDelete` to provide an alternative interface -- probably as additional security.  If you want to delete multiple rows, you need to inquire with whoever wrote that stored procedure or whoever maintains it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should get all duplicate users:

```
delete from users
where user_id  IN
(
  select user_id 
  from Users
  group by user_id 
  HAVING count(user_id ) > 1
)
```

OR

You can write cursor:

```
DECLARE @user_id INT;  
  
DECLARE id_cursor CURSOR FOR   
      select user_id
      from Users
      group by user_id
      HAVING count(user_id) > 1;  
  
OPEN id_cursor
  
FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor   
INTO @Cid   
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    EXEC UserDelete @CID = N'1',
            @UserID = @user_id 
            @DeletedBy = N'System Administrator';

    FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor   
    INTO @user_id 
END   
CLOSE id_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE id_cursor;
```